# append values in python.How?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the FixVersion value for each my JIRA issue in below format from the below code and then I am trying to append the value using append method in python but not getting the desired results

```
  for version in issue["fields"]["fixVersions"]:
    cacheData = json.dumps(version)
    jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)
    #lines = jsonToPython.items()
    if jsonToPython['name'][:8] == "Clignra ":
      Fixversionmatch = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+", jsonToPython['name'])
      match = Fixversionmatch[0]
      print match     
  for i in range(match):
    allModules.append(i)      
    print allModules
```

from the above code I get the below error

```
for i in range(match):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got unicode.
```

If I remove the below code and just do print match

```
  for i in range(match):
    allModules.append(i)      
    print allModules
```

then I get the below output
after remove and get no unicode:

```
Processing TTPT-2
1.4
2.4
2.5
Processing TTPT-1
2.4
```

The output which I am trying to achieve is below

```
Processing TTPT-2
[1.4, 1.4, 1.5]
Processing TTPT-1
[1.4]
```

Comment: `re.findall()` will give you a list of strings/unicode. Convert the indices to `int` if you want to use them in `range()`, i.e. `for i in range(int(match))`...

Comment: On the other hand, that won't give you what you want - it will just solve the error...

Comment: Where do you declare allModules

Comment: @Legman sorry I forgot to mention I did that allModules = []

Comment: @zwer I get this ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.5' and if I use float then TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, the error you're experiencing is due to the fact that [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of strings while [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) expects integer arguments. However, to get what you're trying to achieve you'd want to turn your capture into a list, something like:

```
fix_versions = []
for version in issue["fields"]["fixVersions"]:
    cacheData = json.dumps(version)
    jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)
    if jsonToPython['name'][:8] == "Clignra ":
        version_match = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+", jsonToPython['name'])
        if version_match:
            fix_versions.append(version_match[0])
print(fix_versions)
```

Based on your question, this should print: `['4.4', '4.4', '4.5']` (and so on, for the next module...) If you want them as pure floats, you can do the conversion when appending to the `fix_versions` list:  `fix_versions.append(float(version_match[0]))`

Also, any particular reason why are you doing:

```
cacheData = json.dumps(version)
jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)
```

? This should result in an equal structure so you can completely omit it and perform your match on the `version` directly, i.e.:

```
fix_versions = []
for version in issue["fields"]["fixVersions"]:
    if version['name'][:8] == "Clignra ":
        version_match = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+", version['name'])
        if version_match:
            fix_versions.append(version_match[0])
print(fix_versions)  # `['4.4', '4.4', '4.5']` etc. or similar
# or:
print("[{}]".format(", ".join(fix_versions)))  # `[4.4, 4.4, 4.5]` etc.
```

Comment: this is already I did but the problem am I getting with this is [u'4.4']
[u'4.4', u'4.4']
[u'4.4', u'4.4', u'4.5'] if u have multiple fixversion in issue

Comment: @Sushant - that's because `print()` prints the representation of your list. If you want to remove the metadata check the updates above.

Comment: I think my problem is when I have multiple fixversion in issue for e.g. 3 then it iterates three times in output [4.4]
[4.4, 4.4]
[4.4, 4.4, 4.5] and append the first in 2nd and 2nd in 3rd but I need final only

Comment: @Sushant - Make sure you're printing it outside of the `for version in issue...` loop as presented above. When it comes to Python, indentation **matters a lot**!